# A nice looking twitter crawler widget and a feed crawler widget?

Tags: 12.10, software-recommendation

I am a heavy twitter user and would want a twitter crawler widget that will auto update and keep showing tweets as a widget on the home screen.

I use gwibber, polly etc, but they are twitter clients...not twitter crawler widgets.

I also use feeds a lot, so would like any feed crawler widget to...preferably a google reader client.

Any suggestions?

Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

As what concerns a feed reader, I would reccomend these, available from the Software Center :

- LightRead
- Una Reader
- Feedivore
- Pressboy
  Source : OMG! Ubuntu

I did not find Ubuntu twitter crawlers, so I don't suppose they even exist, sorry...

That's all I can do, mjchopperboy

Comment: I couldnt find any in the software center! o_o  and also, are they crawler widgets? not just apps?

Comment: They're feed reader apps

Comment: Oh...I dont want apps... I want widgets :(